# I am getting error in factorial program written in python

Tags: python

I am getting the wrong answer.

```
n = input()
factorial = 1
if int(n) > 1:
    for i in range (1,int(n)):
        factorial = factorial * i
print(factorial)
```

expected output for 2 is 2

But I am getting 1. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code prints also for value 1

```
n = input()
factorial = 1
if int(n) >= 1: #added = symbol
    for i in range (1,int(n)+1): #added 1 to the upper limit
        factorial = factorial * i
print(factorial)
```

Answer (score 3):

`range()` goes until `n-1` and not `n`. So, add 1 to `int(n)`.

```
n = input()
factorial = 1
if int(n) > 1:
    for i in range (1,int(n)+1): #added 1 to the upper limit
        factorial = factorial * i
print(factorial)
```